# WebBrowser.DocumentText from other Thread (read Access)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

On my Mainwindow (`Form1`) there is a WebBrowser Element which navigates to certain targets. (Most the time invoked from Threads)

Now I need to get the `DocumentText` of that WebBrowser from within a Thread. Trying to do this results in an Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in System.Windows.Forms.dll

The Exception appears in the Following Line (within the Thread):

```
String newContent = webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString();
```

Accessing the DocumentText in the same way from within the main-thread works.

I cannot create a WebBrowser Element inside the Thread, cause i need do deactivate various Scripting Elements, and then i receive the Excception:

```
"Window handle of control element "AxTriggerCtrl" could not read. 
"Windowless ActiveX-controls are not supported"
```

I want to use a WebBrowser rather than a WebClient because it needs to follow various (javascript) redirects, meta refreshs and Ajax loaded content.

I potentially *could* create  a Form2, containing a Webbrowser, invoking that from the thread and using that - but I hope there is another solution :)

Any ideas?

---

Gusman was right. Using a delegate solved the Issue.

```
        public delegate String GetWebBrowserTextThread();
        public String GetWebBrowserText()
        {
            if (webBrowser1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                GetWebBrowserTextThread gwbtt = new GetWebBrowserTextThread(GetWebBrowserText);
                return (String)webBrowser1.Invoke(gwbtt);
            }
            else
            {
                return webBrowser1.DocumentText;
            }
        }
```

and from the thread:

```
String newContent = cfg.ApplicationForm1.GetWebBrowserText(); //cfg is just a configuration singleton
```

Should have tried that before asking - would have saved some time and headache :)

Comment: Why not create a global variable, set it to `webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString();`, then set your string to the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a desktop app use the Invoke function of any control to execute a piece of code in the UI thread, else if you are in WPF you can use Dispatcher.Invoke to do the same.

Comment: Thought about that, too. But until now It was never required for "read" access. Also the Exception does not state any cross-thread-issues which is what kept me away from "trying" this.

Comment: You are not 100% sure what's going under the hood, so it may be needed to be in main thread. As a rule of security whenever you interact with UI do it on main thread.

Comment: That's true. And that was the case.